# Java (eclipse): Any way to System.out.println this String from a JOptionPane .showInputDialog?

Tags: java, string, swing, comparison, joptionpane

Code's here:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Comienzo {

    public static void main() {
        String nombrepersonaje = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Introduce el nombre de tu personaje");    

        if (nombrepersonaje == null)
            Principal.main(new String[]{});
        else if (nombrepersonaje.equals(""))
            Comienzo.main();
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido... " + nombrepersonaje + "!");

        Start.main();
    }    
}
```

I've tried since yesterday several ways to call a String, but it only works if String is defined before

```
    public static void main ()
```

So, question is this: How can I "System.out.println" String `nombrepersonaje` from another class in same Java Project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as "calling a String". Can you rephrase what you're trying to do?

Comment: Rephrased: How can I "system.out.prinln" String nombrepersonaje from another class in same Java Project? (Thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field in the other class. Add a setter for the field. Create an instance of the class with `new`. Call the setter with the variable `nombrepersonaje`.

```
public class Start {
     private String name;
     public void setName( String name ) { this.name = name; }

     public void run() {
          ...
     }
}
```

and in `Comienzo`:

```
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido... " + nombrepersonaje + "!");
    Start start = new Start();
    start.setName(nombrepersonaje);
    start.run();
}
```